# Why are all the avatars of Vishnu born in North India?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, birth

Ayodhya, Indraprastha, Kailasha parvatha, all these religious birth places are mostly in the North. Why weren't none of the the avatars born in other parts of Bharathavarsh?

Comment: Ahobilam (**Andhra**)- Narasimha; Malaya mountain (Tamraparni river or Kritamala [Vaigai] can’t place which in **Tamil Nadu**)- Matsya Avatar; Tirupati (**Andhra**)- Venkateswara and also Varaha avatar went and settled there and hence it came to be known as Varahakshetra. Parashurama happened in Maharashtra somewhere (again South). *In the North there is only Ayodhya and Mathura.*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prahladpuri_Temple,_Multan  narasimha seems to have appeared in Multan, Pakistan.

Comment: the question has to be changed to "which avataras happened in north india"

Comment: @SK it hasn't changed

Comment: I think anybody can edit it @Vivikta

Comment: @Archit, i'd like to see a person from Maharashtra say that they're from the south. Yes, narasimha isn't from south.